# Update existing picklist values with a Global value set

Tags: picklist, global-picklist

I have a custom picklist with few values in Account object. This field is referring in apex classes and visualforce pages. I want replace its existing values with a global value set. When I edit the picklist field I cannot see option for doing that. I can see option for adding global value set only when new picklist field is created.

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In case of editing of the picklist field, ability to change it to global value set is shown  as action button on the top.

Check Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you cannot yet do what you are asking. The other answers here assume you want to convert an existing Picklist to a Global Value Set but I don't believe that's what you're asking. I think you are asking if you can convert an existing Picklist to use an existing Global Value Set. According to [this post](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJegAAE) you cannot do what you are wanting and Salesforce does not intend to add the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the existing picklist values can be changed to get values from global picklist.

The field must be restricted picklist values and must not contain more than 1000 values.

And then you can promote the picklist to a global value set

Comment: but can you update the field to reference an existing global set?  Say I have two fields on two different objects with the same values, and I want them to share a global set.  I can promote one, but there doesn't seem to be a way to update the other to reference the set i just created